# Mobile Website Optimization

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm making a new website. It will be blog style, but made from scratch rather than using existing templates or software (like WordPress) mainly for the sake of experimentation.

My question is, what should I do to make the site optimized for mobile devices? I'd like to optimize it with a style that's made to fit on smaller screens, but without creating a separate page and redirecting based on the device the user is viewing on. Basically, I want to create one page of content, two stylesheets, and a surefire way of the making the appropriate stylesheet apply based on what type of device the user is viewing on.

What's the best method of doing this?

Comment: Have a look at http://mediaqueri.es/ and http://simplegrid.info/ they use media queries based on browser width. @media all and (min-width:XXpx){}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just looking for a way to detect the browser and apply the correct CSS?  If that's all, try using [CSS Media Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).  You could set one of your style sheets to `screen` and another to `handheld`:

```
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="screen" HREF="desktop.css">
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="handheld" HREF="mobile.css">
```

This leaves it up to the device/browser to determine which type it wants to use, as opposed to trying to force users into a certain style based on some kind of browser detection from the server.

Another benefit of this approach is if you use CSS to define a lot of your image resources (instead of `img` tags).  The `handheld` style sheet can use fewer of those resources, so the mobile browser never even knows or cares about them.

Comment: For this method, is what you've stated all that is required? For example, media="handheld" is defined somewhere?

Comment: @rar: See the link I posted.  Standard media types are defined by W3C published standards, and as such most browsers (especially any which care about their styling and display) should support them.

Comment: I'm having a problem with it. I've posted exactly the following

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="mobile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="desktop.css">
 and it only seems to use the desktop one.

Comment: @rar: Can you be more specific?  What browser?  Can you test it on other mobile browsers as well?  Maybe that mobile browser is using the `screen` media type?

Comment: I've tried on Android (using HTC's default browser as well as Dolphin HD) and on iOS (mobile Safari).

Comment: @rar: Interesting.  Does it use the `handheld` one at all?  What if you take out the `screen` one?

Comment: @rar: A little Googling turned up this: http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/optimizing-websites-iphone-and-android/  I guess Android and iOS browsers don't use `handheld` the way other devices do.

Answer (score 0):

Creating separate stylesheets for both variations is a great idea but as you said "optimized for mobile", simply having customized CSS is not enough.
There are other factors which make a website mobile friendly like website loading speed, content, user experience on mobile etc.

To dive more into this topic you can take help of this post on [mobile optimization](https://www.social9.com/blog/proven-tips-to-optimize-wordpress-blog-for-mobile/).